# Change format date using javascript from timestamp php

Tags: laravel, vue.js

can javascript change the date format taken from php like this: `2018-09-22 05:20:48` to like this `Saturday,22 September` ? iam using vue.js and laravel. because this date is taken from the database using a query i dont know how to get int time and it will be passing to vue component.

**Vue Component :**

```
    <tr v-for="(category,index) in allCategories">
                  <td class="v-align-middle"> <img :src="category.images[0].link" class="img-fluid categoriesImg" alt=""> </td>
                  <td class="v-align-middle">{{category.category}}</td>
                  <td class="v-align-middle">{{formatDate(category.created_at)}}</td>
                </tr>



<script>



    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
export default {
  name:"category",
  computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        allCategories:'allCategories'
      }),

    },
    created(){

        // this.$swal('Hello Vue world!!!');

      this.$store.dispatch('GetAllCategories');

    },
    methods:{
      formatDate(date){
        let tanggal = new Date(date);
        return tanggal;
      },
    }

}
</script>
```

**Result**

```
"2018-09-21T22:20:48.000Z"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) is the best soltion.

Make sure you set the right format (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```
formatDate(date){
    let tanggal = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('dddd,DD MMMM');
    return tanggal;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code :

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var dayNames=['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
d = new Date(date);
time = dayNames[d.getDay()] + ", " + d.getDate() + monthNames[d.getMonth()] ;
```

For more information you can checkout the [Date](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) in javaScript